# Apply font styling to browser tab text

Tags: css, browser, favicon

**EDIT**

Well, a full decade after asking this question, an answer was placed that actually acheieved it.

However, in the meantime, I learned about **accessibility**. I don't recommend doing what I was trying to now. There is a layer of accessibility that sits above what the individual web developer, deisgn or business does, in the space where the person is using the browser across all sites.

Other things there are the focus styling and back button behaviour. These things should be consistent across all sites for a good accessibility experience.

So, while I commend Vlad's inginuity and would take the position that a mind that can come at problem from different angles to find solutions, [as has been demonstrated there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77623459/1249829), is valuable to cultivate in oneself as a software engineer, I would not recommend actually either following my decade previous self, or the answer, in an actual site.

**10 YEAR OLD QUESTION**

Is it possible to apply font styling to the text in the browser tab, as in the text that displays the page title beside the favicon. So that when a user looks at their browser tabs and my site is open in one of them they see the title written in my sites choice of font ?

Comment: No, not possible. Tabs are by definition "outside" of the area that your html can affect. The only thing you CAN change is the content of the text, via the `<title>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

No I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that shows that browser tabs may display fonts in specific styles. Save the following code as "tabfont.html" and open the file in a webbrowser (tested on Firefox 120, Safari 15.6).

```
<html><header><title>  •   - YouTube</title><meta name="title" content="  •  "></header><body><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uktj2MYSsaU">Hello!</a></body></html>
```

The method consists in using letters from the mathematical Unicode range. Here is a list of options:

- ,  ,
- ,
- ,
- 
- ,  ,  ,
- 
- , , , ,

Comment: This German translation from DeepL of the first example exposes a problem I didn't consider in 2013: " ,  ,   " - accessibility! Plus, the advantage of consistent tab font stylings to the user is probably greater than my design feelings. Nice hack though, I wouldn't recommend it in production,

Comment: You are right Toni, about the accessibility issue. I was positively surprised, however, to see that the text was correctly spelled in speech by Google Translate.

Comment: I think this means I can't upvote the answer, but I'm also going to add that blurb about accessibility to the question, so I'll mention this answer

Comment: The text is also spelled correctly in the translated text becuase it's unusual unicode chars and not really English text, therefore the translator can only repeat it back out again, as with other non-text chars - btw, I used DeepL translator, which is better than Google Translate[1], by not being Google, but also by being better in other ways, and could actually do the job, maybe via it's "capture text on screen" feature, however, even that would struggle with the Script Bold example, which looks very unreadable. ... [1] DeepL handles fewer languages than Google Translate